# Cuando leo algun correo,no me lee algunos adjuntos. Uso el protocolo IMAP el cual contiene la dll S22.IMAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail, imap

Tengo el siguiente codigo, en el cual uso el protocolo IMAP que contiene la dll S22.IMAP:

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient(imap, 993,
               usuario, psw, AuthMethod.Login, true))
        {
            foreach (var uid in client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen()))
            {
                var message = client.GetMessage(uid);                      
                foreach (Attachment atc in message.Attachments)
                { 
                  if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(atc.Name) == ".xml")
                    {
                        String archivoXML_texto = "";
                        byte[] allBytes = new byte[atc.ContentStream.Length];
                        int bytesRead = atc.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)atc.ContentStream.Length);
                        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes))
                        {
                            StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory);
                            archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                            archivoXML.Close();
                            memory.Dispose();
                        }
                  .......
                  .......
                   }
                }
             }
           }
```

pero tengo un problema, cuando trato de leer el adjunto de algun correo, 
me doy cuenta en la depuración del codigo que no está leyendo el adjunto. 
Lo extraño de este suceso, es que ocurre con algunos correos, tanto como correos gmail y privados(no digo que todos de estos dominios no lee los adjuntos), los demás los lee bien.

Me gustaría saber cual sería la causa que me impide leer estos correos. ¿Podría ser que haya alguna configuración de privacidad, por ejemplo en gmail,
 que haga que bloquee los adjuntos en el codigo?, y si fuera cierto, ¿como lo habilitaria? ¿o tendría que cambiar la forma de implementación del codigo? ¿y cual sería la mejor o algun buen ejemplo?

Desde ya, gracias, espero su ayuda por favor.

Comment: No lee ninguno de los que tiene adjunto? Lee _algunos_? Revisa si hay en el buzón de correo, alguna directiva que limite la descarga de los adjuntos por SMTP a un tamaño máximo y si la librería tiene algún método para realizar la descarga por aparte.

Comment: si lee adjuntos, pero en algunos correos que llega, no los lee.

Comment: Puede que sea a) que esté fijado ese límite de descarga de adjuntos, o b) que se estén bloqueando los archivos XML. Si quitas la validación de la extensión XML y simplemente pruebas listar/imprimir el nombre de los adjuntos que lee... qué ves?

Comment: No, es mucho antes, no es por el tipo de documento, cuando voy por la linea de codigo var message, depurando, empiezo a revisar sus componentes, en Attachments, me sale cont=0, es decir que no trae adjuntos, y lo curioso es otros correos que tambien traen adjuntos, los lee, es decir en la depuracion sale Attachments: count=1

Answer (score 1):

Podria ser algun bag en la libreria, no intentaste usando alguna otra?, por ejemplo

[MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

esta tiene ejemplo donde descarga el attach

[ImapExamples.cs](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/ImapExamples.cs)

analiza si con otras libreria sucede el mismo efecto

Comment: no,  voy a probar, y te cuento

Comment: en paquetes de nuget, busco MailKit, pero me dice MailKit' ya tiene una dependencia definida para 'MimeKit'., porque nombre deberia buscarlo para descargarlo en el nuget del visual studio??

Comment: si revisas el primer link al final tiene el titulo "Installing via NuGet" y enciona como agregas la referencia usando nuget

Comment: ok, esta viendo cual sería el atributo para leer los correos no leídos usando el MailKit, en el caso de mi pregunta con la dll s22.Imap era Unseen, en SearchCondition.Unseen()

Comment: sería así:var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);?

Comment: si revisamos el ejemplo del segundo link seria var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.All);

    foreach (var uid in uids) {
var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (uid);

Comment: Voy bien hasta ahora, me lee los adjuntos con este codigo:
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
client.Authenticate ("correo", "clave"); client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly); var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
                foreach (var uid in uids)
                {   var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);
                    foreach (var atc in message.Attachments) {     ..
                    } }

Comment: pero, antes podía obtener y leer el contenido del adjunto, así:
if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(atc.Name) == ".xml")
                            {
                                String archivoXML_texto = "";
                                byte[] allBytes = new byte[atc.ContentStream.Length];
                                int bytesRead = atc.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)atc.ContentStream.Length);
pero ahora se me complica la sintaxis, ya que antes la variable atc era de tipo Attachment, pero ahora me sale el siguiente error:

Comment: No se puede convertir el tipo MailKit.BodyPartBasic en System.Net.Mail.Attachment

Comment: pero un BodyPartBasic  esta claro no es un Attachment, no se que es lo que estas intentando asignar

Comment: publique una respuesta que le falta la lectura del texto del adjunto. tiene una parte solucionada, pero tienes alguna opinión al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39852903/236345) en SO en inglés.

Puede que buscando los mensajes no leídos de otra forma y, luego, recuperando los mensajes completos, funcione la lógica de tu código.

Para efectos de hacer esta respuesta algo más que un link, añado el código relevante:

Primero esto

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage> mails = new List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage>();

using (var imap = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", mailAccount.UserName, mailAccount.Password, AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true)) 
{
    var msgs = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen());
    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++) {
        string msgId = msgs[i].Uid;
        ids.Add(msgId);            
    }

    foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        mails.Add(imap.GetMessage(id, headersonly: false));
    }
}
```

Y luego esto

```
foreach(var msg in mails)
{
    foreach (var att in msg.Attachments) 
    {
        string fName;
        fName = att.Filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: mailAccount.UserName, mailAccount.Password, AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, que son? el nombre usuario, pasword y correo que debo colocar?ya que así tal como esta escrito, me sale error de sintaxis

Comment: el atributo Uid, en donde está string msgId = msgs[i].Uid;, no me la reconoce, pero si la reemplazo por ToString(), ahí me reconoce el codigo, pero me sale error en la ejecución:
{"No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder."}

Comment: No transcribas literal. A la primera pregunta, sí, son los parámetros de conexión al servidor SMTP. A la segunda, es verdad, eso no va a funcionar sin toString porque sospecho que ese Uid es un long o algo así

Answer (score 0):

Encontre una solución a medias:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
            client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            client.Authenticate ("correo@gmail.com", "clave");
            client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);

            foreach (var uid in uids)
            {
                var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

                  }                   

                foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments.OfType<MimePart>())
                {
                        String archivoXML_texto = "";
                        byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.Content.Stream.Length];
                        int bytesRead = attachment.Content.Stream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.Content.Stream.Length);

                      // string texto_prueba=attachment.ContentBase

                        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes))
                        {
                            StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory);
                            archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                            archivoXML.Close();
                            memory.Dispose();
                        } 
                }
            }
```

Pero tiene un gran detalle, cuando quiero obtener el texto del adjunto, que contiene la variable archivoXML_texto, me lo muestra en binario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que deseo es obtener el texto o string del adjunto, tal como sale en la foto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, en la depuración, en el atributo Text, sale el contenido que necesito guardarlo en una variable tipo string, pero se me transforma el texto del adjunto en texto binario. ¿Alguna recomendación?

Observación, me di cuenta que viene como base64.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Actualización de la respuesta mejorada:**

Pude solucionar mi problema, dejo el código, pero se puede mejorar:

```
 public static void DownloadBodyParts ()
    {
        using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
            client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            client.Authenticate ("correo@gmail.com", "clave");
            client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            //var query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains ("MimeKit").Or (SearchQuery.SubjectContains ("MailKit"));
            var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);

            foreach (var uid in uids)
            {
                var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);
                foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments.OfType<MimePart>())
                {                       
                    //if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) == ".xml")
                    //{
                        byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.Content.Stream.Length];
                        int bytesRead = attachment.Content.Stream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.Content.Stream.Length);
                        string texto_definitivo = "";
                        String archivoXML_textoBase64 = "";
                        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes))
                        {
                            StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory);
                            archivoXML_textoBase64 = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                            byte[] temp_backToBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(archivoXML_textoBase64);
                            texto_definitivo = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(temp_backToBytes);
                            archivoXML.Close();
                            memory.Dispose();
                        }   

                   // }      
                }
            }

            client.Disconnect (true);
        }
    }
```

El objetivo es poder obtener el contenido/texto del adjunto que viene en el correo, me di cuenta que obtenía el binario en base64, por lo que tuve que convertir la variable archivoXML_textoBase64, que viene como un string de base64 a binario y este pasarlo a string.

Me imagino que habrá alguna manera mas directa de hacerlo, pero esa es la solución que se me ocurrió.